# Expiring Rails action cache off-line when using memory store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using Rails action caching with the memory store:

```
# controller
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :index

  def index
  end
end

# product sweeper
class ProductSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  def after_create(record)
    Rails.logger.info "expiring"
    expire_action :products, :index
  end
end

# application.rb
config.active_record.observers = :product_sweeper
config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

When I view the show action in the dev console, the action gets cached as expected.

When I fire up a dev console, and I create a new product, I see the sweeper/observer after_create fire.  However the cache is not expired.

I assume this is because Rails memory cache is not globally shared between processes?  Since I plan to create new products in the background (running in a cron periodically), is this possible, or do I need to change from memory store to another cache strategy?